# Can't deploy Rails app with Capistrano and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano

I have a Rails app that I've been deploying with Capistrano. I installed RVM on the server since I wanted to use a newer version of Ruby and added this to my deploy.rb file (per various instructions I found):

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

When I run, `cap deploy`, this happens:

```
    [staging.example.com] executing command
 ** [out :: staging.example.com] /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (
 ** [out :: staging.example.com] Gem::LoadError)
 ** [out :: staging.example.com] from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
 ** [out :: staging.example.com] from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
 ** [out :: staging.example.com] from /usr/bin/bundle:18
    command finished in 801ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/example/staging.example.com/releases/20110714180125; true"
    servers: ["staging.example.com"]
    [staging.example.com] executing command
    command finished in 895ms
    failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ /usr/local/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c 'bundle install --gemfile /home/example/staging.example.com/releases/20110714180125/Gemfile --path /home/example/staging.example.com/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development production'" on staging.example.com
```

Why is capistrano using Ruby 1.8? My path is obviously messed up, too.

Here's the output of `rvm info` on staging.example.com:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180:

system:
  uname:       "Linux staging 2.6.39.1-linode34 #1 SMP Tue Jun 21 10:29:24 EDT 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
  bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
  zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
  version:      "rvm 1.6.22 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

ruby:
  interpreter:  "ruby"
  version:      "1.9.2p180"
  date:         "2011-02-18"
  platform:     "i686-linux"
  patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
  full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]"

homes:
  gem:          "/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
  ruby:         "/home/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"

binaries:
  ruby:         "/home/example/.rvm/bin/ruby"
  irb:          "/home/example/.rvm/bin/irb"
  gem:          "/home/example/.rvm/bin/gem"
  rake:         "/home/example/.rvm/bin/rake"

environment:
  PATH:         "/home/example/.rvm/bin:/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/home/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/example/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/ruby/bin"
  GEM_HOME:     "/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
  GEM_PATH:     "/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180:/home/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
  MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180"
  IRBRC:        "/home/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/.irbrc"
  RUBYOPT:      ""
  gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Are you using a .rvmrc file with your project? If so, is it pointing to the right ruby and gemset?

Comment: Here's what's in my .rvmrc: `rvm_gemset_create_on_use_flag=1
rvm_trust_rvmrcs_flag=1` Not sure how to get it to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. The .rvmrc file is used to specify which ruby and gemset you want to use with this project. I usually create mine like this: > echo "rvm 1.9.2@myproject" > .rvmrc Now when I cd into that directory, rvm will automatically switch to ruby version 1.9.2 and change my gemset over to myproject.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the latest docs on rvm-capistrano documentation page stated that it must be something like this:

```
# RVM bootstrap: change to your Ruby and GemSet
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string,  ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")
set :rvm_type, :user
```

Answer (score 2):

```
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ /usr/local/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2' -c 'bundle install --gemfile /home/example/staging.example.com/releases/20110714180125/Gemfile --path /home/example/staging.example.com/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development production'
```

Make sure you have bundler installed and right path while running `bundle install` in server. If it is not installed then run `gem install bundler` to install.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bundler installed, do this:

Change this line --> `set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'`

to this --> `set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p180'`

this works for me.

to know your rubys versions --> `rvm list`